# Polyfill for ReadableStream.from in browser?

Tags: javascript, stream, cross-browser, polyfills

[`ReadableStream.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/from_static) for browsers is currently only supported in Firefox. I found the [Node implementation in JavaScript](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/webstreams/readablestream.js#L1311), but it uses a lot of internal native node functions. Likewise, `ReadableStream.from.toString()` in Firefox's console reveals that its implementation is also a native function.

Is there a pure JavaScript implementation I can polyfill in temporarily? Perhaps using `ReadableStream`s constructor? I imagine the appropriate pull and cancel callbacks can be written based on the underlying iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ReadableStream polyfill on GitHub (https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill) that includes a polyfill for [`ReadableStream.from`](https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill/blob/master/src/lib/readable-stream.ts#L339):

```js
const stream = ReadableStream.from(["Hello", "World!"]);
const reader = stream.getReader();

function process({ done, value }) {
    if(done) {
        console.log("(end of stream)");
        return;
    }
    console.log(value);
    reader.read().then(process);
};

reader.read().then(process);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web-streams-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```